# Configuring bash alias for virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, bash, virtualenvwrapper

I have compiled Python 2.7.6 from source in Ubuntu 12.0.4.3. It can be found in `/opt/python276/bin/python2.7`

I then created `alias python276=/opt/python276/bin/python2.7` in `.bashrc`

in the bash terminal, I can type python276 and receive the correct interpreter, but when I try to create a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper:

```
puffin@ubuntu:/opt/python276/bin$ mkvirtualenv test -p python276
The executable python276 (from --python=python276) does not exist
```

What am I missing? I can create virtualenvs with the system python, but not the compiled one.

** Edit **

I eventually found exactly what I was looking for. 
The way to create a virtualenv without having to specify the actual path is by creating a symlink. In this situation, I would create a symlink from the Python executable to `~/bin` then prepend `~/bin` to my path.

```
ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 ~/bin/python33
echo 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I can then do `mkvirtualenv testenv -p python33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note an alias works when calling it. If you use it as a parameter of another command, it is not interpreted. Hence, in your `mkvirtualenv ...` you should specify explicitly the path of this python.

Otherwise, you can set a variable

```
mypython276=/opt/python276/bin/python2.7
```

and then do

```
mkvirtualenv test -p $mypython276
```

---

As said in comments, you can also add `/opt/python3.3/bin/` into the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Is this the only way around this? I'm sure I have been able to use the alias in the past.

Comment: As far as I know, yes @puffin . Could you show those cases in which aliases could be used in the past? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Nah, can't find an example. I must be mistaken.

Comment: I have edited my answer as I was able to find an example where using a symlink would have the effect I was looking for.

Comment: Good point! It makes me think that the symlink step can be skipped by adding `/opt/python3.3/bin/` into the PATH variable